# get spesific ID customer from tables react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap-table

I try to GET customer ID from tables and after that I wanna to use that ID for Request to my API.
but I got Stack, I am confuse for passing the customer ID to my logic method **updateCustomer(customerId)** and **deleteCustomer(customerId)**

my dependencies version:

```
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "4.1.5",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^3.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^1.3.1",
```

this is my **columns** in **ToolkitProvider**:

```
{
              dataField: 'action',
              text: 'Action',
              formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => { 
                  console.log(row);
                  const customerId = row._id;
                  return ( 
                    <div >
                      <span className="mr-1">
                        <a onClick={this.updateCustomer(customerId)} className="text-warning">update</a>
                      </span>
                      <span className="ml-1">
                        <a onClick={this.deleteCustomer(customerId)} className="text-danger">delete</a>
                      </span>
                    </div> 
                  )
                },
            }
```

my logic method just for testing whether the user id has been accepted:

```
  updateCustomer = (id) => {
    return alert('ok your id: '+id)
  }
  deleteCustomer = (id) =>{
    return alert('ok your id: '+id)
```

and this my **Actions Tables** look like:

[image]

but when I click it, I only get repeated **alerts** as much as customer data in the table.

how do I get the right ID in the method I provide?
I am Stack.

I Hope you can help me,
Thanks:)

Comment: What does this produce: `console.log(row);`

Comment: all exiting data customer  per row @DarrenSweeney

Comment: Can you show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I can solved this problem by my self. 
I just change `onClick={this.updateCustomer(customerId)}` to this `onClick={() => this.updateCustomer(customerId)}`

maybe that means: **"just run the function after the action"**

```
{
              dataField: 'action',
              text: 'Action',
              formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => { 
                  console.log(row);
                  const customerId = row._id;
                  return ( 
                    <div >
                      <span className="mr-1">
                        <a onClick={() => this.updateCustomer(customerId)} className="text-warning">update</a>
                      </span>
                      <span className="ml-1">
                        <a onClick={() => this.deleteCustomer(customerId)} className="text-danger">delete</a>
                      </span>
                    </div> 
                  )
                },
            }
```

and I don't get repeated alerts again:)